# Unable to clear my REPUTATION - deadly embrace

Tags: discussion

My reputation got hammered by an Admin, as I:
1) Answered my own question
2) and placed it in the wrong "forum" - ServerFault instead of SuperUser.

So I deleted it. BAD IDEA.

I am now locked out of Answering ANYONE'S questions in SuperUser, as I was supposed to somehow "fix" my answer and clear it up that way.  Well, I can't, because it created a deadly embrace of some kind.  (You can't fix what doesn't exist.)

Can anyone clear this lock, so that I can answer questions again?

Comment: You should ask this question on a meta forum. And as far as I know the locks are temporary. Anyhow, I had the same thing before with Ask Ubuntu (after some warnings, if I remember well). I opened a new account and now I know which site to avoid. If your description is complete, then it's a rather harsh treatment.

Comment: Thanks for the commiseration. It was rather harsh and berating as well to try to help others and get slammed for it.  I would open a new account, but my reputation on other "forums" is up there, after years of posting, and I'd rather not lose that.

Comment: Reading the [Help Centre](https://superuser.com/help) is always a good idea on any site... right now you're just compounding your error by posting this here instead of Meta :/ btw, one user can only "hammer" you to the value of 3 invisible internet points... 2 for the question & 1 for the answer.

Comment: I didn't have much to lose. Some people seem to have no outlet for their frustrations. I marked this question for moving to meta, so hopefully it gets moved there soon. I wonder why you got locked on SE if you misposted on SF?

Comment: Since this is the first time I've even heard of the "Meta" site, and it having the ability to be posted to, seems a bit draconian to yet again punish for asking a relevant question of this nature on *any* forum here.  Also, when the count for a question is "1", and someone puts you to "-1", and you delete the question - you're locked out of that forum - from my personal experience here.

Comment: From your profile dashboard, click the **Question** link, and then *deleted recent questions* which appears at the bottom. This should allow you to get back to the question, undelete it, and clean things up (if you can).

Comment: @BeeKay - your current frustration levels seem to be of your own making. Honestly, the more you flail at the system, the more people will downvote, the more you will be 'locked out'. It's a self-fulfilling prophesy in the end. Suck it up, be the bigger 'man/woman/gender of your choice', participate, gain reputation, enjoy.

Comment: Other than being a spammer, you don't get locked out of anything based on one post.  There's either information you aren't including here, or you have misinterpreted something.  It can be sorted out on the Meta site.

Comment: @Tetsujin What a sadistic world view. I could call your comment a self-fulfilling prophesy as well. The guy's been around for more than 4 years and gets locked out without a warning. Isn't something wrong here?

Comment: @Tomasz: (1) As fixer1234 says, you don’t get locked out based on one post. It feels like the OP is not telling us the whole story.  (2) The OP’s been around for more than four years (member of 14 communities, active in 9), and they haven’t heard of Meta, and refer to [SE] sites as “forums”. Isn't something wrong here? (Then again, I notice that *you* also used the word “forum”. See [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/195817))

Comment: @Scott No, I don't think that changes anything. 1. Maybe he (or she) doesn't know or remember the whole story? What about presenting people a warning that they're on the edge when they try to post, with relevant info? 2. Why would anyone need to know about the meta? A regular user shouldn't care. It's meta, after all. 3. Think of the four years account as opposed to a rather temporary spammer or troll account, which should be locked out quickly. 4. I'm not going into the discussion whether this is a forum or not. A pure word game. I advise a healthy dose of flexibility in semantic mind-frame.

Comment: @Tomasz "A pure word game" – no. In a cinema you shouldn't act as if you were in a gym. Here you shouldn't act as if it was a forum. Different places, different purposes, different names. If you're not convinced yet, then think about your kitchen vs. your toilet.

Answer (score 10):

#### Can anyone clear this lock, so that I can answer questions again?

The answer is unfortunately no, as it is an automated block.

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban answers from accounts that have posted numerous low-quality answers in the past. These filters help keep the quality of our sites high.

...

> **How can I get out of an answer ban?**
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines
> that your positive contributions outweigh those answers which were
> poorly received.
>
> **Stack Exchange cannot lift answer bans by request.**
>
> The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the
> site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". Begin by fixing your
> existing answers; do not just post the same answer again or delete all
> of your existing answers. All answers are expected to be useful to
> future visitors, in addition to the original asker, so keep the
> following tips in mind when improving your answers:

...

Source [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/answer-bans)

So far, on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), you have posted 3 (currently deleted) answers with a total score of -1.

- 2 were answers that did not really answer the question and should have been comments.
- The other was an answer that was essentially saying thank you for another answer.

I've undeleted the only answer that I think can be improved (https://superuser.com/a/1107906/337631).

Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), and try and improve yours (hint: It needs to be a **standalone** answer that **completely answers the question**).

Notes:

- You are not currently blocked from asking questions on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).
- Any issues you have with your account on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) should be raised on [their meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/).

Comment: I have no "existing answers" to fix, so I can't undo those items.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, and for relocating this to Meta SuperUser.  Apparently I managed to time out between my initial comment and my edits, so a second comment.

Comment: You shouldn’t be submitting “thank you” comments anyway.  If an answer is helpful it should be upvoted.  If an answer, to your own question answers your question, accepting the answer is appropriate.  “Thank You” commentary is typically just removed when flagged.  Help Center and numerous Meta StackExchange questions confirm this.  Your answer van isn’t personal, but your answer ban, is caused by not understanding what is expected out of an answer it seems.  Our basic expectations are outlined in the help center (for example not submitting commentary as an answer).

Comment: (1) I’m curious why you undeleted the OP’s “answer” rather than just telling them to edit it and undelete it (or flag it for undeletion) themselves.  (AFAIK, even low-rep users can see and edit their deleted posts — although *finding* them is tricky.)  Why not just give them a link to the deleted post(s), and reiterate [Jason Bassford’s advice](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13140/150988#comment36394_13140) on how to find deleted recent posts?  (2) I don’t see how the OP is likely to able to improve [their answer](https://superuser.com/q/816014/150988#1107906)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  to [How do you stop the process of deleting an account on Mac?](https://superuser.com/q/816014/150988) other than cosmetically, without copying from the other answer, unless they have some better information that they aren’t telling us about. (3) +1 for “Any issues you have with your account on [SF] should be raised on [their meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/).”

Comment: @Scott It was mod deleted, so could not be undeleted by the OP or community votes.

Comment: I realized that; that why I added the “(or flag it for undeletion)” note. Are you saying that a mod-deleted answer can’t be edited or flagged by its author?

Comment: @Scott Yes. That's exactly the case. "If your post was deleted by a moderator, you can flag one of your other posts and write a note in the "other" section explaining the situation and requesting undeletion." See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: @scott Or, or course, if you have no active posts to flag, you can ask on meta :)